# Rollover within a table keeps going vertical

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have been trying to make a table that displays 3 pictures horizontally that change individually on rollover.hover. But the images keep going under each other vertically.

If you could help that would be great.

```
<table style="width: 678px; height: 380px; cellpadding: 0; cellspacing: 1 "> 
<tbody> 
<tr align="center"> <td style="width: 220px; height: 380px;"> 
<style type="text/css"> #first-div.rollover a {
    display: block;
    width: 225px;
    height: 380px;
    background-image: url(IMG1a);
}
#first-div.rollover a:hover {
    background-image: url(IMG1b);
}
</style><div class="rollover"> </a> </td><td style="width: 220px; height: 380px;"> <style type="text/css"> #second-div.rollover a {
    display: block;
    width: 225px;
    height: 380px;
    background-image: url(IMG2a);
}
#second-div.rollover a:hover {
    background-image: url(IMG2b);
}
</style><div class="rollover"></a> <td style="width: 220px; height: 380px;"> <style type="text/css"> #third-div.rollover a {
    display: block;
    width: 225px;
    height: 380px;
    background-image: url(IMG3a);
}
#third-div.rollover a:hover {
    background-image: url(IMG3b);
}
</style>
<div class="rollover"></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table> 
<div class="rollover" id="first-div"> 
<a href="link1"></a> </div> <div class="rollover" id="second-div"> 
<a href="link2"></a> </div> <div class="rollover" id="third-div"> 
<a href="link3"></a> 
</div>
```

Comment: If you need to place CSS inline (you don't) then keep it in one place, on the top of the page. Right now your code is very hard to read.

Comment: I have just been looking over it a lot and can't see why it is going on a new line. I didn't have the different images ID’ed before with "<div class="rollover" id="first-div"> 
<a href="link1"></a> </div> <div class="rollover" id="second-div"> 
<a href="link2"></a> </div> <div class="rollover" id="third-div"> 
<a href="link3"></a> 
</div>" and it was fine before I started doing that - But I need that to make each image individual.

Comment: Your markup contains several errors, for example you are trying to close <div> tags with closing </a> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good practice to separate your CSS in a different file. If you have to use inline CSS (which you really don't) make sure to put it all in one place, inside the `<head>` tag.

You had a lot of errors in your markup (some listed below). I have cleaned up your code and provided you with a working example in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V3x6w/

- You are closing tags that never have been opened (`</a>`) on lines
  13,22,32.
- You have multiple `<style>` tags inside the table
- Your `<div>` tags with a background image are not inside the table.
- Cellspacing and cellpadding are not css attributes, but HTML attributes - use them like so: `<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"`